# Scroll to top area in div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that has CSS as following,

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100px;"> long Text....</div>
```

The issue is long text is shown and vertical scroll bars shown but when browsing the page div is scrolled to bottom and end of the of the long text is shown instead from beginning portion of long text.

Any way to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: could you put up a sample page at jsbin.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this :

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:100px;"> 
  <div style=" height:500px;">
     long Text.... 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what this does

Comment: @DSharper - its allow to create scroll because inner div have more size than parent one ...